# Map API that can layer Geotagged photos

Tags: android

I'm looking for a speicifc Map that can be used in mobile software. For my project I'm mapping a sets of photo, is there any recommendation for my needs? Thank you.

I'm clueless for what I'm going to use. I hope someone help me.

Comment: `looking for a speicifc Map that can be used in mobile software. ` ,,,???? Pretty unclear where you are after. 'I'm clueless'.